# How can I view the current GCP quota on the number of projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

On the "New Project" page I used to see a warning telling me that I only have X projects remaining in my quota. I requested an increase for this quota and it seems to have worked because I no longer see that warning.

My problem is that I cannot find anywhere what the new quota is and how many projects I actually have.

The documentation states:
"You can see the number of projects you have remaining in your quota on the New Project page."
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/limits

This is not true. It is not on that page.

Also, the documentation states:
"If you have fewer than 30 projects remaining in your quota, a notification will display the number of projects remaining in your quota on the New Project page."
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#managing_project_quotas

This is correct, I used to see that message before the quota increase. But where can I see the number of projects I currently have and the current quota?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I’d like to point out here:

- First off, when submitting for a project quota increase using the
  [form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase), an e-mail is usually sent to you within a few business
  days informing you on whether the request has been approved or not;
  so the immediate way to know whether it has been granted, is by
  checking your e-mail. If you haven’t received it yet, the request is
  most probably still being processed, and I'd advise you to wait until at least 48 business hours have passed since the submission.
- The [first](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/limits) documentation link referring as to how to view your current
  project quota is likely outdated, as you indeed used to be able to
  view how many projects you can create at the [New Project](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate?_ga=2.100121051.-431281023.1570474299) page, but
  was later changed to only be displayed for when you reach a certain
  threshold of the quota, in which case, the [second](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#managing_project_quotas) link is the one that is 
  probably
  most up to date; also meaning, that if you no longer see the warning
  mentioned in it, your request has probably been approved, but again,
  to be sure, it’s better if you check your e-mail. There are currently no other 
  ways you can check your project quota that I know of.
- This brings me to the next point; if you’re still unsure, or have not
  received a response after a few business days, then feel free to
  [contact Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/), informing them of your situation and
  they’ll assist you best.

Comment: This does not answer the question. On https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas you can view all your quotas in GCP, but there are more than 1 Mio different quotas. What is the name of the quota for the total number of projects per organization?